# Sharepoint 2013 pasting text into a cell of multiple lines type

Tags: custom-list, excel, copy-and-paste

I am trying to copy & paste a cell of data from excel to my sharepoint list. The excel cell of data consists of multiple lines of text, so when I copy & paste in the data it pastes it onto more than one row rather than all in the same cell. The column is of type "multiple lines of text" & I have tried changing the "Specify the type of text to allow:" radio button to each of the three, but still with the same result.

I have attached a couple of screen grabs as I'm more than likely not making any sense.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If i try pasting in multiple columns I then get this error: "The format of the clipboard data is not recognised"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get around this problem by creating a VBA macro in the excel speardsheet to get rid of line breaks and replace them with "br" tags. Then when I pasted over the data the list accepted how I wanted it.

I hope this helps others out, here's a link to what i used for the macro. It's number 3:
http://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/03/remove-carriage-returns-excel/

Answer (score 1):

If you are uncomfortable using Macros, you can try the below.

I used =clean(A1) in excel to create a friendly chunk of text to copy and paste into SharePoint. That way the text gets cleaned from Excel first, before pasting into SharePoint. I used Excel 2013 and SharePoint 2013.
[image: Using the clean formula in excel]

[image: Pasting into SharePoint, into one cell as opposed to multiple cells.]